# Celery Worker ImportError for unused task

Tags: python, celery

I have the following setting:

- Two servers, x and y, that handle basic tasks, and one server z, that only handles magic related tasks.
- I have two different projects for basic and magic tasks, i.e., the tasks are also distributed among different modules. Let's call them `basic.tasks` and `magic.tasks`.
- I have a single Celery app that is managing the routes for x, y, and z. In the constructor, it contains `include=['basic.tasks', 'magic.tasks']` to make the app aware of both modules and tasks.

Now, I would like to avoid always cloning and updating the `magic` repository on servers x and y, since these servers do *not* execute these tasks. However, when it is not added to the corresponding worker's `PYTHONPATH`, I receive an import error: `ImportError: No module named magic.tasks` on startup.

Any thoughts/ideas how to circumvent this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help & best regards,
Fabian

Comment: Make `magic.tasks` an empty module / file on the basic tasks project? You don't need to clone the repo / code if it is not used.

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly an option. I was hoping for some configuration trick. But this workaround could save me definitely time and work.